# single page application (SPA) home page error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application

I am new to asp .net MVC. I am trying to implement SPA model for my new application. I am using asp .net web api in asp .net mvc4 project. I have only api controllers in my project. I dont have any MVC controllers.

I have deleted auto generated views from the views folder. I have created a index.cshtml page outside the views folder. This page is my layout page that renders other pages in it. I have set this page as startup page. And also i have commented out the default MVC route from routeconfig.cs file.

The problem is when i run the application, the index.cshtml does not render. I get an error saying "This type of page is not served  -  Description: The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.cshtml' may be incorrect."

Please help

Comment: What URL do you hit, when you get the error? You should hit a Controller and Action, such as `http://localhost/Home/Index` - you should then have your `Index.cshtml` file placed in the root `Views` folder in a folder named `Home`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you keep the root `Views` folder, and create a folder called `Home` within that. Place your `Index.cshtml` file within the `Home` folder.

**Do not comment out the default MVC route.** In MVC, you can't hit a view directly, as you do in WebForms, which is why you get the error when you try to hit `Index.cshtml`.

Make sure you have a `HomeController` within the root `Controllers` folder, with an action called `Index` that looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View();
}
```

Your view should now render when you browse `http://localhost/Home/Index` or even just `http://localhost` as by default, the controller and action will be set to Home/Index.